# How to modify CSS of placeholder attribute in a textarea/input tag?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to modify the font size of the text in the placeholder attribute of a text area element. I can do this using vanilla CSS, but when I attempt to mimic the idea in my app--an Angular 2 app using Angular Material 2--I cannot obtain the desired behavior. In vanilla HTML/CSS I can simply do the following:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="foo" placeholder="goodbye enemy!"></textarea>
```

**CSS**:

```
#foo::-webkit-input-placeholder{font-size: 100%;}
```

I simply modify the percentage value to modify the size of the placeholder text. However, when I attempt to try the same approach with Angular Material, I cannot modify the font size.

The Angular Material 2 doc on the input directive is here: [Docs on the Angular 2 Material Input Directive](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview). I've played around with the plnkr associated to it but cannot modify the placeholder text using the given approach. Does anyone know why? The docs state that the `<md-input-container>` is simply a wrapper for the native input/textarea tags so I am not sure if it is overriding some sort of behavior in the background. Any help would be appreciated.

[An earlier SO discussion that could also be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: Are you not wanting to use `mdInput` in your textarea DOM?

Comment: Did you use the browser dev tools (f12 usually) to give you clues as to whether your id or placeholder attribute is intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secret is that you don't need to style the **input**, but rather the generated **label**.

Considering the label for the placeholder is generated inside a `<span>` that immediately follows the `<input>`, you can target it with:

```
input + span > label {
  color: red !important;
}
```

The `+` denotes that you're only looking to target the very next matching element, and the `>` denotes a direct child.

This can be seen working in **[this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6XeQrsrCSdLcOBHhg3pc?p=preview)**.

Note that the `!important` declaration is required for the selector above, because it has **lower [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** than selectors in Angular's example CSS. Ideally, you'd want to provide higher specificity instead of using `!important`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Worth noting this works for `textarea` as well, but only works in both with use of `mdInput` attached to the inner DOM.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, how did you recognize the correct combination of css selectors that was required? (The whole input + span > label business). I actually still can't seem to modified the generated label in my app using your technique, but I'm trying to target the correct combo of css selectors.

Comment: I worked it out through simple trial-and-error in the Angular example. By using the F12 Developer tools, I noticed that the `<label>` generated was placed inside a `<span>`, which directly followed the `<input>`. Thus, I used `input + span > label` to give a high level of specificity, so that I wouldn't need to use `!important`. Sadly, I needed that anyway. It's all just a matter of specificity though. Regardless of structure, it **will** be a `<label>` nearby in the DOM. Simply adjust the selector to suit. You could even just target `input` if need be. Note that you may need `!important`.

Comment: Thank you. It looks I'm on the same approach but things are not working out with getting the correct combination of selectors. If I posted the code from the dev tools, could you take a look?

Comment: It could be a little difficult; you'd need to post a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and that could be a bit tricky if you can't find that target element. I'd strongly recommend 'Inspecting' the element with F12 to find out **exactly** where it sits in the DOM. You can then craft your selector around that. If you're still unable to change the color, it's possible that something else has **higher specificity**, and you'll simply need to work up the chain in that case (also by trying using `!important` to start with).

Comment: I was able to fix it, but it involved fixing something in the global styles sheet of the application. Thank you for your help (and your patience!).